# C++ classes do not compile

Tags: c++, class, linker, makefile

I'm trying to learn object-oriented programming in C++, but I'm having trouble compiling the following simplified example:

**TestBank.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Bank.h"

int main()
{
    Bank deBank;
}
```

**Bank.h:**

```
#ifndef BANK
#define BANK

class Bank
{
  public:
    Bank();
};

#endif
```

**Bank.cpp:**

```
#include "Bank.h"

Bank::Bank() {
    //
}
```

When I'm trying to execute `make TestBank`, I get the following error:

```
c++     TestBank.cpp   -o TestBank
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Bank::Bank()", referenced from:
      _main in TestBank-480209.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [TestBank] Error 1
```

What is causing this behaviour? It seems like `Bank.cpp` is never included. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to compile and link against `Bank.o`.

Comment: The problem appears to be in your Makefile. You either don't have one, or the options have not been set up properly...